# Change sprite by changing array index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sprite

I'm writing a simple spelling game and want to cycle through available letter sprites when left key pressed.

I can load these sprites ok:

```
 function loadSprite(fileName){
    assetsStillLoading++;

    let spriteImage = new Image();
    spriteImage.src = "assets/sprites/" + fileName;

    spriteImage.onload = function()
    {
        assetsStillLoading--;
    }

    return spriteImage;
}

sprites.letterA = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_A.png');
sprites.letterB = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_B.png');
sprites.letterC = loadSprite('/Letters/letter_C.png');
```

Here's my string array:

```
var lts = [
"letterA",
"letterB",
"letterC",
"letterD",
"letterE",
"letterF"
 ];
```

So, when I click leftbutton I want to display next sprite image:

```
Letter.prototype.letterLeft  = function(){

console.log("left");
letterNo = letterNo + 1;

var string = "sprites." + lts[letterNo];
console.log("sprite loading:" + string);
this.sprite = string;
```

}

But, I get error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.
```

I have been googling for hours trying to find ways of casting the string to an object or change sprite from array, tried several attempts, but can't perform this simple action ;-(

EDIT: to show drawimage:

```
GameWorld.prototype.draw = function(){
Canvas.drawImage(sprites.background, {x:0, y:0});

for(let i=0; i < this.letters.length; i++){
    this.letters[i].draw(DELTA);
}

this.whiteBall.draw();
```

}

Comment: Do you call drawImage somewhere? If yes can you provide the code snippet?

Comment: user148397 added drawImage